# Using Symfony with OPcache - full cache

Tags: php, caching, symfony, opcache

Some of my websites are hosted on a server with OPcache activated which improves the performace greatly but I have the problem of the cache getting full fast. Then on some pages I tend to get an error 502, which - of course - is a major problem. The only way to overcome this is by manually clearing the cache but that helpes only shortly. My hosting provider told me that they tried some changes (which didn't help for me) and that I cannot expect a memory increase for OPcache anytime soon.
When I've tried disabling OPcache, the load for the server was too high, so I need to keep using it.

The biggest site I have running there is based on Symfony3. Others sites are just relatively small pages, but one of them - where I also experience problems - is based on Silex (a Symfony micro-framework).

Is there any way I can improve the performance of the OPcache directly from Symfony? Or anything settings changes I could suggest to my hosting provider?

Thanks

Here's an example output from `opcache_get_status(false)` if it helps:

```
[opcache_enabled] => 1
[cache_full] => 1
[restart_pending] => 
[restart_in_progress] => 
[memory_usage] => Array
    (
        [used_memory] => 25118936
        [free_memory] => 46888
        [wasted_memory] => 0
        [current_wasted_percentage] => 0
    )

[interned_strings_usage] => Array
    (
        [buffer_size] => 4194304
        [used_memory] => 4194292
        [free_memory] => 12
        [number_of_strings] => 102372
    )

[opcache_statistics] => Array
    (
        [num_cached_scripts] => 1074
        [num_cached_keys] => 1989
        [max_cached_keys] => 3907
        [hits] => 302267
        [start_time] => 1468984961
        [last_restart_time] => 1469018698
        [oom_restarts] => 0
        [hash_restarts] => 0
        [manual_restarts] => 1
        [misses] => 6467
        [blacklist_misses] => 0
        [blacklist_miss_ratio] => 0
        [opcache_hit_rate] => 97.9053165508
    )
```

Comment: This is one of the many reasons why we always (strongly) suggest people to get a VPS instead of being dependent on some 3rd party.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Well, they call it a VPS hosting and I have a number of options I can set there but I don't have complete control over everything. And I probably also don't have the complete knowledge to setup the whole server myself.

Comment: Well if you are paying for a managed VPS I don't see any reason why they wouldn't give you some more memory.

Comment: 2PeeHaa: Thanks but that doesn't answer my question. Is there anything that helps in this situation (or anything I am doing wrong) besides increasing memory for opcache? (I'm really no expert on opcache, so I am happy about constructive hints.)

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong, your opcache size is simply too small for the amount of scripts that want to go into it.

Increasing the memory size would be the only option.

Be prepared to then also increase the number of scripts allowed, because as more scripts can be cached, your system may hit this other limit, and leave memory unused. The maximum is `max_cached_keys`, and your current usage is seen under `num_cached_keys`.

For the record: Using PHP 7 will reduce the amount of memory every script will need in the opcache, so upgrading will improve the situation by itself: More scripts would fit into the same amount of memory, and it's faster code execution.